# Understanding an Error Trail from Spin Modelchecker

Tags: model-checking, spin

I am trying to use Spin Model Checker to modelcheck a Game between two objects (A and B). The objects move on a board, and each location is defined by its (x,y) coordinates. The two objects are supposed to not collide. I have three processes: init, A Model, B Model. I am model checking an ltl property: (liveness property to check if the two objects ever occupy same location)

```
ltl prop1 { [] (!(x_a == x_b) && !(y_a == y_b)) }
```

The error trail that I get is:
  init -> A Model -> B Model -> init

However, I should not get an error trail (counterexample) based on the data that is shown: x_a=2, x_b=1, y_a=1, y_b=1.

Also the first init does go through all the lines of init process, but the second one only shows to the last line of it.

Also my A Model and B Model only consist of guards and actions in a 'do' block as shown below. However they are more complex and have if blocks on the right of '->'

```
active proctype AModel(){
do
:: someValue == 1 -> go North
:: someValue == 2 -> go South
:: someValue == 3 -> go East
:: someValue == 4 -> go West
:: else -> skip;
od
}
```

Do I need to put anything in an atomic block? The reason I am asking is that the line that the error trail is showing does not even go into the 'do' block, and it is just the first line of the two models.

EDIT: 
The LTL property was wrong. I changed that to:

```
ltl prop1 { [] (!((x_a == x_b) && (y_a == y_b))) }
```

However, I am still getting the exact same error trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LTL property is wrongly implemented.  Essentially, the counter example that SPIN found is a true counter example for the LTL as stated.

```
[] ( !(x_a == x_b) && !(y_z == y_b) )   =>
[] ( !(2 == 1) && !(1 == 1) )  =>
[] ( !0 && !1) =>
[] ( 1 && 0)   =>
[] 0  =>
false
```

The LTL should be:

```
always not (same location) =>
[] (! ((x_a == x_b) && (y_a == y_b))) =>
[] (! ((2 == 1) && (1 == 1))) =>
[] (! (0 && 1) =>
[] (! 0) =>
[] 1 =>
true
```

Regarding your init and tasks.  When starting your tasks you want to be sure that initialization is complete before the tasks run.  I'll use one of two approaches:

```
init { ... atomic { run taskA(); run taskB() } where tasks are spawned once all initialization is complete`
```

or

```
bool init_complete = false;
init { ...;  init_complete = true }
proctype taskA () { /* init local stuff */ ...; init-complete -> /* begin real works */ ... }
```

Your LTL may be failing during the initialization.

And based on your problem, if you ever change x or y you'd better change both at once in an atomic{}.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I changed the LTL property but I am still getting the exact same error trail, and counterexample.

Comment: Is the LTL that I provided causing the counter example (see above, it shouldn't).

Comment: Yes, it does. That is why I am confused. I feel like there should be a problem with putting things in atomic blocks. Because originally I didn't have my init process in an atomic block and the counter example would just go to the first line of init. But after putting init in an atomic block, the counterexample goes through all the lines of init, then only the first line of A Model and B Model, and then the last line of init.

Comment: So I am initializing like the first way you mentioned: init{ atomic{ /*initialize the board and values */}} but do I need to run taskA() and run taskB() from inside init(). I assumed that Spin will go to taskA and taskB without the need of me calling them.

Comment: A proctype will start automatically if it is declared with 'active' as:  active proctype taskA () { ... }.  But then it will run at anytime and in particular during your init steps.  When I use 'active proctype' then I initialize with my second approach.  If you don't use 'active' then you must call 'run'.

Comment: Alright, I have active proctype so I tried the second initialization. Still getting the same counterexample :( Anything on the righthand side of '->' should also be executed atomically right?

Comment: No.  '->' is in all ways equivalent to ';'  !!

Comment: Okay! The problem was that before init process the default values in x-a, x_b, y_a, y_b were all zero. So the ltl property would fail. I'd need to initialize the globals directly in the declaration.